# React.js handling a date change across components that aren't parent/child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a layout component in react (below). Two of my components that get injected into this component via this.props.children (or now childrenWithProps) have a date-range component that I created for them that allows the user to select the range of data that is pulled from teh api. One is a player dashboard and one is a team dashboard (default view and shown in second code block). When a user is on the team dashboard and searches a player and moves over to that player dashboard i want the date range selected (which is stored as this.state.startDate and this.state.EndDate) to carry over into the player dashboard, and then vice versa. I feel like this is a good use case for redux, but thus far I have managed to get by just passing props and the redux implementation for date range seems daunting. Any help would be much appreciated. Also, i'm new to react and know i need to do a fair amount of reformatting.

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import '../../styles/core.scss';
import TopNav from 'components/top-nav';
import LeftNav from 'components/left-nav';

export default class CoreLayout extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element
 };

constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        team: null,
        teamPositions: []
    };
}

activeTeam(team){
    console.log(team);
    this.setState({
        team: team
    }, () => {
        return this.state;
    });
}

componentWillMount() {
}

getTeamPositions(positions){
    this.setState({
        teamPositions: positions
    }, () => {
        return this.state;
    });
}

render() {
    var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => React.cloneElement(child, { team: this.state.team, teamPositions: this.state.teamPositions }));
    return (
      <div className='page-container'>
          <TopNav
            onTeamChange={team => this.activeTeam(team)}
            sendTeamPositions={positions => this.getTeamPositions(positions)}
            />
          <LeftNav />
          {( this.state.team !== null ) ?
        <div className='view-container'>
          { childrenWithProps }
        </div>
        : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Team Dashboard

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { getDataRange, getTeams, getFile, getAllHitsData, getPlayers} from 'api/index.js';
import moment from 'moment';
import {Table, Thead, Th, Tr, Td} from 'components/Reactable';
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import ScatterPlot from 'components/scatterplot';
import DashboardStats from 'components/dashboard-stats';
import DateRangeComponent from 'components/date-range';
import AdminSquare from 'components/admin-square';

let allHitDatas = [];
let hitDatas = [];
let teams = [];
let newFile = '';
let players = [];

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
   team: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  //  teamPositions: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        showRangePicker: false,
        hitDatas: [],
        teams: [],
        start: '',
        end: '',
        team: this.props.team,
        selectedTeamID: null,
        selectedTeamName: "",
        newFileConfirmation: false,
        players: [],
        allHitDatas: [],
        suggestions: this.getSuggestions(''),
        startDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        endDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        selected: '',
        showDatePickerControls: false,
        showScatterPlot: true
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSuggestionsUpdateRequested = this.onSuggestionsUpdateRequested.bind(this);
}

onChange(event, { newValue }) {
    this.setState({
        value: newValue
    });
}

onSuggestionsUpdateRequested({ value }) {
    this.setState({
        suggestions: this.getSuggestions(value)
    });
}

  formatDate(date) {
    return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }

  formatDisplayDate(date) {
    return moment(date).format('MMMM DD, YYYY');
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
      this.setState({
         team: this.props.team,
         selectedTeamID: this.props.team.id
     }, () => {
         this.dataChangeHelper();
     });
      console.log(this.props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    let defaultStartDate = "03/01/15";
    let defaultEndDate = "05/18/16";
    const config = {
        start: this.state.startDate || defaultStartDate,
        end: this.state.endDate || defaultEndDate,
        team: this.props.team.id
    };

    getAllHitsData(config)
    .then((response) => {
      allHitDatas = response.data;
      this.setState({
        allHitDatas: allHitDatas
      }, () => {
          return this.state;
      });
    });

    getDataRange(config)
        .then((response) => {
            hitDatas = response.data;
            this.setState({
                hitDatas: hitDatas,
                start: config.start,
                end: config.end
            });
        });
    getTeams().then((response) => {
        teams = response.data;
        this.setState({teams: teams});
    });

    getPlayers().then((response) => {
        players = response.data;
        this.setState({
            players: players
        }, () => {
                return this.state;
        });
    });
}

getSuggestions(value) {
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;
    return inputLength === 0 ? [] : players.filter(player =>
        (player.NameFirst.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue || player.NameLast.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue)
    );
}

getSuggestionValue(suggestion) { // when suggestion selected, this function tells
  return suggestion.NameFirst;   // what should be the value of the input
}

renderSuggestion(suggestion) {
  return (
    <span><Link to={ "/view-player/" + suggestion.id }>{ suggestion.NameFirst + " " + suggestion.NameLast }</Link></span>
  );
}

shouldRenderSuggestions(value) {
      if (value) {
          return value.trim().length > 0;
      }
}

renderReactable(hitDatas) {
    return hitDatas.map((hitData) => {
        // console.log(hitData);
        if (Number(hitData.playerTeamId) === Number(this.state.selectedTeamID) || this.state.selectedTeamID === null) {
            return (
                <Tr key={hitData.MaxHic}>
                    <Td column="name" data={hitData.playerNameLast + ', ' + hitData.playerNameFirst} />
                    <Td column="numHits" data={hitData.numHits} />
                    <Td column="maxHic" data={Math.round(hitData.MaxHic)} />
                </Tr>
            );
        }
    });
}

renderReactableTwo(allHitDatas) {
    return allHitDatas.map((hitData) => {
        // console.log(hitData);
        if (Number(hitData.playerTeamId) === Number(this.state.selectedTeamID) || this.state.selectedTeamID === null) {
            return (
                <Tr key={hitData.Hic}>
                    <Td column="name" data={hitData.playerNameLast + ', ' + hitData.playerNameFirst} />
                    <Td column="hic" data={Math.round(hitData.Hic)} />
                </Tr>
            );
        }
    });
}

dataChangeHelper() {
  console.log(this.props);
    const newConfig = {
      start: this.state.startDate,
      end: this.state.endDate,
      team: this.props.team.id
    };

    getDataRange(newConfig)
    .then((response) => {
      hitDatas = response.data;
      this.setState({
        hitDatas: hitDatas
      });
    });
    getAllHitsData(newConfig)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      allHitDatas = response.data;
      this.setState({
        allHitDatas: allHitDatas
      });
    });
```

}

```
showNewDateRange(newStartDate, newEndDate) {
  this.setState({
    startDate: newStartDate,
    endDate: newEndDate
    // showDatePickerControls:false
  }, () => {
    this.dataChangeHelper();
 });
}

handleImpactClick(d) {
 console.log(d);
}

render () {
  if (this.state.teams.length === 0 || this.state.players.length === 0) {
    return (
        <div className="no-data-container">
            <div className="no-data-message">We don't have any data for you right now. Would you like
                to add some players, teams, or devices?
            </div>
            <ul className="no-data-links">
                <AdminSquare title="PLAYER ADMIN" icon="person" link="/player"/>
                <AdminSquare title="TEAM ADMIN" icon="group" link="/team"/>
                <AdminSquare title="DEVICE ADMIN" icon="sd_storage" link="/device"/>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
const inputProps = {
  placeholder: 'Search for a player',
  value,
  onChange: this.onChange
};

return (
    <div>
        <div className='admin-table-wrapper'>
            <div className="homeview-subnav">
                <div className="view-title">Team Data</div>
                <DateRangeComponent
                    startDate={this.state.startDate}
                    endDate={this.state.endDate}
                    onDateChange={(newStartDate, newEndDate) => this.showNewDateRange(newStartDate, newEndDate)}
                />
                <Autosuggest
                    suggestions={suggestions}
                    onSuggestionsUpdateRequested={this.onSuggestionsUpdateRequested}
                    shouldRenderSuggestions={this.shouldRenderSuggestions.bind(this)}
                    getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue.bind(this)}
                    renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion.bind(this)}
                    inputProps={inputProps}
                />
                <button className="retrieve-file-trigger" onClick={this.retrieveFile.bind(this)}><i className='material-icons small file-icon'>file_download</i></button>
            </div>
            <div className="top-dashboard-data-container">
                <div id="home-scatter-container">
                  <ScatterPlot
                    data={this.state.allHitDatas}
                    statOneTitle='HIC'
                    location='#home-scatter-container'
                    showScatterPlot={this.state.showScatterPlot}
                    sendHitData={(d) => this.handleImpactClick(d)}
                 />
                </div>
                <DashboardStats
                    impactsRecorded={12456712}
                    devicesActive={27}
                    highestHic={234}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="table-wrapper">
            <div className="table-title">TOP HICS</div>
            <Table
                className="table table-dashboard"
                itemsPerPage={10}
                pageButtonLimit={5}
                noDataText="No data available for this filter set"
                sortable
                defaultSort={{column: 'hic', direction: 'desc'}}>
                <Thead>
                    <Th column="name">
                        <strong className="name-header">NAME</strong>
                    </Th>
                    <Th column="hic">
                        <strong className="position-header">HIC</strong>
                    </Th>
                </Thead>
                { this.renderReactableTwo(this.state.allHitDatas) }
            </Table>
            </div>
            <div className="table-wrapper">
            <div className="table-title">MOST HITS</div>
            <Table
                className="table table-dashboard"
                itemsPerPage={10}
                pageButtonLimit={5}
                noDataText="No data available for this filter set"
                sortable
                defaultSort={{column: 'maxHic', direction: 'desc'}}>
                <Thead>
                    <Th column="name">
                        <strong className="name-header">NAME</strong>
                    </Th>
                    <Th column="numHits">
                        <strong className="position-header"># OF HITS</strong>
                    </Th>
                    <Th column="maxHic">
                        <strong className="position-header">TOP HIC</strong>
                    </Th>
                </Thead>
              { this.renderReactable(this.state.hitDatas) }
            </Table>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can manage state anywhere you like (or even anywhere you don't like). You can just use a global variable, or a local variable. You could pass an object down the tree with props with some properties describing your range. This could be a local variable. The main issues with this approach are that it's not standard and not extensible. Redux solves both these. If this is too much hassle, just use [redux-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-schema) (disclosure: I wrote it).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I'd say the best bet without redux is to move the date range state into a parent component that encapsulates both dashboards, like the CoreLayout for example and pass the range down as props.

It is worth looking into switching to Redux though, it looks daunting at first but it really is super simple after you give it a go, does makes life easier.

Comment: Yeah that was my first approach but then i realized there are a bunch of child views that are admin views inside of CoreLayout that don't have the date range and the search in them.

Comment: I think where I'm losing it with redux is trying to write my reducer. In the original incrementer action i am looking at i have a line that looks like     `export const increment = createAction(INCREMENT, (value = 1) => value);` but i know that i need something more like `export const startDate = createAction(DATE_CHANGE, (value = 1) => value);` but not sure how to handle the value part of the statement. I'm assuming it will be receiving the date from this.state.startDate in one of my components.

Comment: So yeah, this is about where I get lost with redux.